# I am having trouble solving this problem. I don't know how to parametrize this curve and sketch the direction of the curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

[image]

I'm pretty sure how to find arc length using the formula. But I'm stuck on 1a. I solved for x for the second equation and got $ \ x \ = \  \frac{(2-z)}{\sqrt{3}} \ \ . $ I then substituted this into the first equation to get $ \ \frac{4(2-z)^2}{3} + y^2 = 4 \ \ . $ Where do I go next? How do I parametrize and find the direction of the curve?

Comment: Phrases in titles such as "I am having trouble with this problem" are irrelevant noise.  Of *COURSE* you're having trouble... that's why you're posting here.  Likewise "I don't know how to..." is a waste.  Finally, never post unsearchable text;  instead use *MathJax*.

Answer (score 1):

You've got $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$, so trig functions are probably a good place to start. Set
$$\vec{r}(t) = (\cos(t) , 2 \sin (t), z(t))$$
One easily checks that $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$ is satisfied by this parametrization. It remains to choose $z(t)$ so that $\sqrt{3}x + z = 2$ is satisfied. But this is easy enough. Just set $z(t) = 2 - \sqrt{3}x(t) = 2 - \sqrt{3}\cos(t)$. We finally obtain the parametrization
$$
\vec{r}(t) = (\cos(t) , 2 \sin (t), 2 - \sqrt{3} \cos(t))
$$
Finish up by calculating arc length using the standard integral formula.

Comment: I get x is generally cos and y is generally sin... but why 2sin(t) in the first equation? How do you know it satisfies 4x^2 + y^2 = 4?

Comment: @Vulcan Plug it in and check. As to how I came up with the parametrization, stare at it and see if you can figure it out. This is a standard trick and one you should figure out for yourself.